# NativeScript with ApolloClient issue

Tags: angularjs, nativescript, typescript-typings, apollostack, apollo-client

I created a standard app with `tns create project --ng` which ran fine (and adding platform android)

I also wanted to use graphQL so added apollo-client and graphql tag:

```
npm install apollo-client --save
npm install angular2-apollo --save
npm install graphql-tag --save
```

So now when I build with `tns build android` the error I get is...

```
node_modules/@types/isomorphic-fetch/index.d.ts(7,5): error TS2300:
Duplicate identifier '"audio"'.
```

which clashes with (from what I can see)

```
node_modules/tns-core-modules/declarations.d.ts(25,5): error TS2300:   
Duplicate identifier '"audio"'.
```

isomorphic-fetch is added when apollo-client was added. Not too sure about the typings issue but would be good to know how to get around this.

EDIT:

looking at the [guide](https://medium.com/@iguissouma/using-graphql-inside-an-angular-native-nativescript-app-using-apollo-756a344cd486#.vrhlpjpsn)

I have the 2 items set to false in the tsconfig.json which seem to continue despite of the error...

```
    "noEmitHelpers": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false
```

But I would like to know how to fix this properly.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue but worked around it in a project with the following dependencies:

- nativescript@2.5.1
- typescript@2.2.1 ([bundles `isomorphic-fetch` typings in `dom`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/14765))
- apollo-client@1.0.0-rc.5

This requires changes to `tsconfig.json` and `references.d.ts` described in my response to [Github nativescript-dev-typescript issue 19](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-dev-typescript/issues/19#event-963216101).

While this setup works in the browser with Angular CLI and builds for NativeScript using `tns android` without relaxing  `"noEmitOnError": true` in `tsconfig.json`, I then had to debug a runtime exception with an `apollo-client` call to `redux` which attempts to call `node.js` code leading to the following error:

`ReferenceError: process is not defined
…
/tns_modules/redux/lib/index.js', line: 38, column 4`

This was worked-raound by adding `global.process = { env: {} };` as the first line in `main.ts`, as described in NativeScript Github issue 2937, which StackOverflow won't allow me to link to due to my lack of reputation points.

Answer (score 0):

Well I see tns-core-modules/declarations.d.ts is imported with tns-core-modules/tns-core-modules.base.d.ts so actually Nativescript should provide optionally one more definition where they dont include the request definitions in the base file